# Make grid visible with imagesc (Linux software opengl)

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure

I'm talking about the `grid()` command, not the previously asked and answered questions about showing lines around pixels (data cells).  My image is of scientific data that has relevant axes and I would like the grid to overlay on the image plot.  When I call `grid()`, the grid is there, but `imagesc()` covers it up. I can see it if I change the alpha of the image, but then the image looks grayed out.  Is there another option?

EDIT:  Here's an example of what I want.  It turns out that it works just fine on my Windows machine, but my linux box shows no grid lines as described above. The linux machine uses software opengl.  Any workarounds?

[image]